# Plotting the means in ggplot, without using stat_summary()

Tags: r, ggplot2

In ggplot, I want to compute the means (per group) and plot them as points. I would like to do that with geom_point(), and not stat_summary().
Here are my data.

```
group = rep(c('a', 'b'), each = 3)
grade = 1:6
df = data.frame(group, grade)
# this does the job
ggplot(df, aes(group, grade)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = 'mean', geom = 'point')
# but this does not
ggplot(df, aes(group, grade)) + 
  geom_point(stat = 'mean')
```

What value can take the stat argument above?
Is it possible to compute the means, using geom_point(), without computing a new data frame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do

```
ggplot(df, aes(group, grade)) + 
  geom_point(stat = 'summary', fun.y="mean")
```

But in general its really not a great idea to rely on ggplot to do your data manipulation for you. Just let ggplot take of the plotting. You can use packages like `dplyr` to help with the summarizing

```
df %>% group_by(group) %>% 
  summarize(grade=mean(grade)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(group, grade)) + 
    geom_point()
```